# How to enable desktop effects in Ubuntu 10.4 using Parallels 5 as host

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, parallels

I tried several ways but none of them seem to work.

How can I enable guest Ubuntu 10.4 OS to enable visual effects in OSX host running parallels 5?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=100220) is what I've found useful:

1. Edit the file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/GL.conf`
2. Replace the existing line with `/usr/lib`
3. Execute the command: `ldconfig`

Now the Desktop effects could be enabled.